# Django x Haystack x Solr - How to tell Solr to stop executing a query?

Tags: ajax, solr, django-haystack

*I'm implementing a search with Haystack + Solr using the autocomplete feature. There is a search bar which send by ajax its content to the haystack + solr server. It sends back a rendered html which will be displayed by jquery's .html(). Sometimes the query takes a little bit too long to be executed.*

### How to tell Solr to stop executing a autocomplete query?

### **Example:**

- The user wants to search the name "Oliver"
- On the keyUp event of "Oli" solr gets 100 results. The html will
  takes 0.5s to be processed.
- Meanwhile the user keeps typing and now the ajax send a query for
  "Oliver" which gets 3 results that are instantly displayed.
- The results of "Oli" are received a little bit later so the
  "Oliver"'s results are replaced.

### Would it be possible to send stop message the Solr server? It would solves that issue.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Eric

Answer (score 0):

i have solve this issue with a smarter way. Actually since you can't control the responses you get from the haystack server, i have updated my JS so it checked the html i get back before displaying it. In fact i check if the html match with the keywords of the search bar.